# Cocoapods Not Updating to Latest Version of Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, podfile, podfile-lock

When I run `pod update`, all my other pods update but Firebase only updates to 8.15.0. Firebase is currently on 10.17.0. What's the issue here?

Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
 //...
  - Firebase (8.15.0):
  - GoogleMaps (7.4.0)
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'bottlebin' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myapp

// ... other pods

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Functions'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Installations'
pod 'Firebase/AppCheck'

pod 'GeoFire', '~> 4.0'

pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'PersonalizedAdConsent'

post_install do |installer|

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoFire 4.x requires the Firebase version less than 9.

The change that enabled bumping To Firebase 10.x is updating the Podfile to GeoFire 5.x.  Firebase 10.x supports iOS 11 and up.

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/commit/5624f9cbd3771744afad889588d4b36ac6142e27

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the platform from `'14'` to `'15'`:

```
// 2nd line from top of the Podfile
platform :ios, '15.0'
```